# 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in Windows 10

Tags: java

I know this is a popular question on the web, but I'm getting this error even after setting `JAVA_HOME` env variable and adding `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\` to the Path variable.

I'm trying to use [PDF Presenter](http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net/#) app which requires Java. So, I downloaded Oracle JDK ([jdk-14.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html#license-lightbox)) and installed it and then configured the above two variables.

If I enter `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe --version`, it works fine. But if I enter `java.exe` or `java`, I get the error in the title. How can I fix this?

Here is the output of `echo %PATH%`

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;C:\Users\Nagabhushan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Comment: Please share the full content of your `PATH` variable. Also make sure to restart your CMD after doing any changes to `PATH`.

Comment: have you downloaded javac properly?

Comment: What is the output of "set path"?

Comment: @Zabuzard, here is the output of `echo %PATH%` -> `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;C:\Users\Nagabhushan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;`

Comment: I've restarted cmd as well

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Restarting the computer didn't work

Comment: recheck what you have done by going through this link :- https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Comment: I did all the work and even restarted the terminal but it was not working, the reason was that the advanced settings dialogue box was still open so changes didn't take effect, but once I pressed ok and closed the box and then restarted it, everything was working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the gui of windows for env variable don't use %JAVA_HOME% but the real path.
The variable are not interpreted in the gui.

And in consequence you have %JAVA_HOME% directly in your path who will not be interpreted when you enter your command

Comment: This worked! Thanks a ton. So, I want to switch between java versions, I'll have to edit both `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` right? Is there a way possible to avoid this?

Comment: Thier is no easy solution but a good one is [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/)
Who is like NVM but for java

Comment: @NagabhushanSN I find it weird this solved your problem. On my Windows 10 computer I can use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` no problem (even when set in the GUI editor).

Comment: @NagabhushanSN When you set the value for JAVA_HOME did you type `%JAVA_HOME%` or `JAVA_HOME` for the variable name? You have to use the latter, then in the `Path` you should be able to use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: @Zabuzard Ant, Maven, Gradle, IDEs... they all use this variable in some fashion. It also helps keep things more organized, in my opinion.

Comment: @Slaw I set it as `JAVA_HOME` only, otherwise `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe --version` wouldn't work right? Yes, I know it's good to reuse `JAVA_HOME`, but weird that it didn't work. It would be interesting to know why this problem is happening selectively.

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%` just worked for me on Windows 10 using GUI: https://i.imgur.com/Z9EoqCg.png . Before I added the environment variable, I'd get `java is not recognized as an internal or external command` error when I entered `java -version` into the console.